# Compare Array Contents in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, ios13

I make for fun Uno singlePlayer Game.
I want to compare the following arrays.
I want say
if cards contents is equal to like `blueCards` contents than do something.

Thanks for helping.

```
   let cards = [
        
        "yellow0","yellow1","yellow2","yellow3","yellow4","yellow5","yellow6","yellow7","yellow8","yellow9","yellowskip","yellowreturn","yellow2+",
        "red0","red1","red2","red3","red4","red5","red6","red7","red8","red9","redskip","redreturn","red2+",
        "green0","green1","green2","green3","green4","green5","green6","green7","green8","green9","greenskip","greenreturn","green2+",
        "blue0", "blue1", "blue2", "blue3", "blue4", "blue5", "blue6", "blue7", "blue8", "blue9","blueskip","bluereturn","blue2+",
        "4+",
        "4+",
        "4+",
        "wishcolor",
        "wishcolor", "wishcolor", "wishcolor"
        
        
    ]
    
    
    let redCars = [ "red0","red1","red2","red3","red4","red5","red6","red7","red8","red9","redskip","redreturn","red2+","4+",
                    "4+",
                    "4+",
                    "wishcolor",
                    "wishcolor", "wishcolor", "wishcolor"]
    
    let greenCards = [    "green0","green1","green2","green3","green4","green5","green6","green7","green8","green9","greenskip","greenreturn","green2+",  "4+",
                          "4+",
                          "wishcolor",
                          "wishcolor", "wishcolor", "wishcolor"
    ]
    
    let blueCards = [ "blue0", "blue1", "blue2", "blue3", "blue4", "blue5", "blue6", "blue7", "blue8", "blue9","blueskip","bluereturn","blue2+",
                      "4+",
                      "4+",
                      "4+",
                      "wishcolor",
                      "wishcolor", "wishcolor", "wishcolor"]
    
    let yellowCards = [ "yellow0","yellow1","yellow2","yellow3","yellow4","yellow5","yellow6","yellow7","yellow8","yellow9","yellowskip","yellowreturn","yellow2+",  "4+",
                        "4+",
                        "4+",
                        "wishcolor",
                        "wishcolor", "wishcolor", "wishcolor"
]
```

Comment: You probably need a better way of representing cards than just a string. You could create a struct with a `Color` enum and a value, for example. You would also need properties to indicate wild, draw 4 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you need a better structure for your use case; However, if you really want to go your way then you can do this by doing something like this:

```
func areEqual(card1: [String], card2: [String]) -> Bool{
        if(card1.count != card2.count) {
            return false
        }
        
        for item in card1 {
            guard let _ = card2.firstIndex(of: item) else {
                return false
            }
        }
        
        
        return true
    }
```

This function will first check if 2 cards have the same length, if they don't then it means they don't have the same content otherwise it will go ahead and check every item in `card1` whether it exists in `card2` if any doesn't exist then it will return false.

**EDIT: Please disregard this answer, as was pointed out in the comments, this will work only if the data in cards have no duplicates.**

Comment: Some cards (e.g. "wishcolor") can occur multiple times so your algorithm can give incorrect results (e.g. consider hand 1 is `["wishcolor", "wishcolor"]` and hand 2 is `["wishcolor", "4+"]` the algorithm will return `true`)

Comment: Good catch, that was not clear in the question, but I guess If I had looked carefully at the data I would have seen it.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

So you will know for next time: when asking a question SO guidelines say you should show some effort, e.g. how did you try to solve this problem, where did you get stuck, etc. That said, let's see if we can help you along.

The equality operator, `==`, can be applied to arrays and its description in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array) is:

> `static func == (Array<Element>, Array<Element>) -> Bool`
>
> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether two arrays contain the same elements in the same order.
>
> Available when `Element` conforms to `Equatable`.

Strings conform to `Equatable` so you can compare your arrays of cards.

However you don't say your arrays of cards are kept in any order, so to compare them they will need to be ordered and for that we turn to another `Array` function:

> `func sorted() -> [Element]`
>
> Returns the elements of the sequence, sorted.
> Available when `Element` conforms to `Comparable`.

Strings conform to `Comparable`.

So to compare your two arrays of strings you can use:

```
array1.sorted() == array2.sorted()
```

Some points to consider:

- As others have mentioned, you should investigate defining your own `Card` type rather than using strings. This will make a lot of things both easier to do, as you can make your cards behave as you need them to, and your code easier to maintain and debug.
- Depending on how often you need to compare hands you might want to keep them sorted rather than sort them every time you need to compare them.

HTH